# Creating an EnsureLoggedIn component, that also verifies the stored token with the server

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga

Trying to create an EnsureLoggedIn component that composes other components to decide if to render them or redirect to /login.
My JWT token is in the localStorage. So it need to verify to see if it has expired or not and also fetch the user data along.
I'm using redux-saga. Are sagas only to handle async API calls? I'm not sure where to handle the redirect(browserHistory.push('/'). Do I do this inside the component or in the actions etc. Since the action to verify the jwtToken is async, there's a brief flash to /login while the API calls runs async. Once it succeeds it redirects back to the dashboard. Not sure the best way to deal with this. Here's what i have so far.

```

```
// actions.js
export const LOGIN_TOKEN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_TOKEN_SUCCESS";
export const LOGIN_TOKEN_FAILURE = "LOGIN_TOKEN_FAILURE";
export const LOGIN_TOKEN_REQUEST = "LOGIN_TOKEN_REQUEST";
/* Helper to create Actions */
function action(type, payload = {}) {
  return {type, ...payload};
}

export const login_token = {
  request: (jwtToken) => action(LOGIN_TOKEN_REQUEST, {jwtToken}),
  success: (user) => action(LOGIN_TOKEN_SUCCESS, {user}),
  failure: (error) => action(LOGIN_TOKEN_FAILURE, {error}),
};


// sagas.js
//....
function* verifyLoginToken(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(Api.verifyLoginToken, action.token);
    const response_data = yield response.json();
    if(!response.ok){
      yield put(actions.login_token.failure(response_data));
    }
    else{
      yield put(actions.login_token.success(response_data));

      // TODO Better place to put this?
      // perhaps in the success action creator

      // save token to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem(JWT_TOKEN_KEY, action.jwtToken);

      // redirect to dashboard
      browserHistory.push('/');

    }

  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.login_link.failure(error));
  }
}



// components/auth.js 
//....
class EnsureLoggedInContainer extends Component {
  isLoggedIn() {
    const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    const { user } = this.props
    return jwtToken && user;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // verify token and re-fetch user data in state
    // and action also redirects to dashboard '/'
    // there's a brief flash redirect to /login
    // until the API call to verify token and fetch data makes it through
    // and redirects to '/'
    const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    if(jwtToken) {
      this.props.dispatch(actions.login_token.request(jwtToken));
    }

    if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
      browserHistory.replace("/login");
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { user } =  this.props;
    if (this.isLoggedIn()) {
      return this.props.children
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    user: state.loginToken.user,
    currentURL: ownProps.location.pathname
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EnsureLoggedInContainer)
```

```